# How to resolve a user that has not been interacted yet?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I'm seeking a way to **resolve a telegram user peer when it hasn't been interacted yet** (e.g: I have a list of **Telegram-Users Phone Numbers** that tend to be invited to my Chat/Group/Channel) but **aren't met/interacted yet**, since there's no record for them in the **local .session file**, so there should be a way like **search them in the Telegram-Database** to resolve their Peer-Info needed to use to send the messages/invitations/...

Stay Safe V

Comment: Remember that adding users to your group without consent is considered spam, and will likely get both the group and account deleted.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to resolve a user. If you have their phone number, you can do it using the method to import contacts:

```
import telethon

phone = "+123456789"  # Insert a phone here
contact1 = telethon.types.InputPhoneContact(
    client_id=12345,
    phone=phone,
    first_name="Name",
    last_name="Surname"
)
contacts = [contact1]
resolved_user = client(telethon.functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(
    contacts=contacts
))
```

The `resolved_user` variable will have the information about the found user which you can use in other methods for interaction.